# Showing that a density function of a given r.v. is given by another density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ have a density such that $f_X (μ + x) = f_X (μ − x)$, i.e., it is symmetric about $μ$. Let $Y = 2μ − X$. Show that the density of $Y$ is given by $f_X$. Use this to determine the distribution of $Y$ when $X ∼ N(μ,σ^2)$.

Is this the correct approach?
$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= [F_Y(y)]' \\&= [P(Y \leq y)]' \\&= [P(2μ - X \leq y)]' \\&= [1 - F_X(2μ - y)]'\\& = -f_X(2μ - y)\cdot (-1) \\&= f_X(2μ - y) \\&= f_X(μ + (μ - y)) \\&= f_X(μ - (μ - y))\\& =  f_X(y)\end{align}$$ using the fact that $f_X (μ + x) = f_X (μ − x)$

Also, how can I determine the distribution of $Y$ when $X ∼ N(μ,σ^2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to think about the CDFs. Just observe that

$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(2\mu - y) = f_X(\mu + (\mu - y)) = f_X(\mu - (\mu - y)) = f_X(y). $$

Regarding the distribution of $Y$, recall that two variables with the same density must have the same distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to get into the habit of showing my full thought process, as on tests, some teachers like to deduct marks for "incomplete steps".